# Java execute math equation

Tags: java, math

As you'll probably be able to tell by my way of doing things, I'm a beginner when it comes to Java. Basically I have something like this:

```
 String math = "1 + 1";
```

I want to be able to execute that math equation so that it will return the value 2. Something presumably like this:

```
 String math = "1 + 1";
 int answer = Math(math);
 System.out.print(answer);
```

How would I go about doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about trying something and coming back when you have a specific question? You probably need to start by splitting the string into numbers and operators.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java

Comment: That eval is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks.

Comment: Rhino is built into Java.  Use the JavaScript eval.

Answer (score 0):

use beanshell

http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshmanual.html#eval%28%29

```
Object result = i.eval("1 + 1");  // Integer
```